# Why is SetWindowsHookEx() returning NULL and LastError is ERROR_HOOK_NOT_INSTALLED

Tags: windows, winapi, setwindowshookex

I have code that has been working without any reported issues for a few years. It sets up a low level keyboard hook that the user uses to activate the application.

```
m_hKeyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeybHookFn, GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0);
```

For one user all of a sudden (it worked for him before for years as well), the keyboard hook isn't working. Upon investigation, I can see that SetWindowsHookEx() is returning NULL and GetLastError() is returning **0x00000597**, which is **ERROR_HOOK_NOT_INSTALLED**.

I can't find any documentation on what this means.

What are possibilities for why this might happen? System security settings? User account privileges? The user is using Windows 7.

**I need a specific answer to how to make this error occur so that I can solve the user's problem**

Comment: Proper error checking is never tested.  My crystal ball says that you call UnhookWindowHookEx() when this code fails.

Comment: Once you move that line of code into a DLL, `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` no longer returns the module handle to the module that contains the hook procedure. Using the [`__ImageBase`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/10/25/247180.aspx) pseudo linker variable will fix this issue.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not sure what you're suggesting. Call UnhookWindowHookEx() on which handle? SetWindowsHookEx() is returning NULL

Comment: @IInspectable the code is not in a DLL. WH_KEYBOARD_LL does not have to be used from a DLL. Again, this has all been working on thousands of computers for years.

Comment: You should still use __ImageBase because that's the right thing to do.

Comment: Since the code was working fine before and then all of a sudden stopped working, and assuming you did not change the code recently, then the user must have changed something in the OS.  Installed some app that is blocking hooks, or changed user permissions, or changed UAC settings, or something that is now affecting your app in this manner.

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau, that's exactly the question I'm asking. Can you provide any more detail on where to look? I only have access to the computer via remote session with the user present and would like to not be tinkering blindly if possible.

Comment: @Nicholas: have you asked the user what they changed recently?

Comment: @Nicholas: That being said, have you considered switching to the [Raw Input API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645543.aspx) instead of a low-level hook? Even the [LowLevelKeyboardProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985.aspx) documentation suggests that: "*In most cases where the application needs to use low level hooks, it should monitor raw input instead. This is because raw input can asynchronously monitor mouse and keyboard messages that are targeted for other threads more effectively than low level hooks can.*"

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau. I have asked the user, and they're not aware of any recent changes. I find that users typically do not keep track of their configuration changes but when asked about something specific they often remember doing it. And in the future I'll look into Raw Input API but this is one of those "if it ain't broke..." situations.

Comment: Have you tried getting another process to claim the same hook before yours does?

Comment: @HarryJohnston can you explain what you mean and why it might help?

Comment: @Nicholas: I had misread the question.  However, on the assumption that the problem is caused by some third-party software interfering with yours, I guess you're wanting to try to reproduce what that other software might be doing?  One possibility is that it is registering a low level keyboard hook and not calling CallNextHookEx properly; that *might* confuse Windows enough to prevent new keyboard hooks from being registered.  Another possibility is that security software thinks you're a keylogger and has blocked you, though I don't know why that would only affect one machine.

Comment: Thanks @HarryJohnston. I hadn't considered that it might be another piece of software. But the error happens when setting the hook at SetWindowsHookEx(), so I don't think it's a failure to call CallNextHookEx(). As for security software, that's a good one. I installed an anti-keylogger on a test machine but it didn't have the same effect. I'll ask the user if they have any security software installed.

Comment: It would depend on how the hook mechanism is implemented.  For example, if Windows thinks it is still in the middle of handling a hooked message it might not want to add another hook.  I agree it seems unlikely.

Comment: Have you asked the user to scan for viruses? Even if they have an anti-virus, a quick scan using SpyBot has helped me in many cases like this before.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2010/10/14/global-hooks-getting-lost-on-windows-7.aspx, it seems that it might occur if the CPU load is high.

Another thought: did this break when upgrading to 64-bit windows?  I don't know if applies to LL hooks, but you cannot inject a 32-bit DLL in a 64-bit process.

Finally: LL hooks won't capture input in a UAC-elevated process if the hook was not installed from a UAC-elevated process (a lower privilege level process cannot capture input of a higher privilege level one)

Comment: Regarding CPU level, the scenario is different. In my case, I can't even set the hook.

As for 64-bit, this solution has been fully tested on 64-bit windows and no DLL injection is used anyway.

As for a UAC elevated process, can you clarify?

Comment: @HarryJohnston I clarified the post based on your comment, I did mean what you said in your last sentence.

Comment: Again, this isn't an issue of the hook not working. It's an issue of Windows not allowing the hook to be set in the first place.